# How to redirect simple products to the parent grouped product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, redirect, search, grouped-products

I have simple products that are part of a grouped product, however, when you click on the simple product in the search it does not take the user to the associated parent grouped product - it goes to the simple product page. I need this to redirect to the parent grouped product page as this site will only have one 'child' simple product to one 'parent' grouped product.

How can I accomplish this?

An example is at the following URL: https://wilberline.com/jacketed-batch-reactors-single-dual-glass.html

If you search for the SKU number JRS10 it will show the simple product. When you click on that simple product it should redirect to the grouped product.

Comment: Set visibility of simple products as not visible individually, then simple products will not be included in your search.

Comment: That will not work because then if someone searches for the sku of that simple product they will not find it. The simple products need to remain searchable, but redirect to the group product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround did. I created a text attribute and allowed it to be searchable on the front-end. Then I added the SKU's of the associated simple products to that attribute on the grouped product page. I had to type each SKU in manually and separate them by a comma so it is not as efficient.

The result is a user can search for a simple product SKU and the grouped product that the simple product is associated with will show in the search results.

Comment: Perfect workaround - Just added a new column in my import the same as the associated_skus called child_skus and added the attribute in the backend

Answer (score 1):

@Will Cousin, Magento does not provide functionality to redirect simple product to configurable product by default. I need to create a module and the event/observer to redirect simple product to configurable. Please check [Magento2 Event Observer Redirect Simple Product to Configurable Product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162487/magento2-event-observer-redirect-simple-product-to-configurable-product)